# Updating Cholesky decomposition when deleting one row and one and column.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, covariance, lu-decomposition

I found the answer of updating Updating Cholesky decomposition when deleting one row and one and column on [Cholesky decomposition when deleting one row and one and column.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896467/cholesky-decomposition-when-deleting-one-row-and-one-and-column)

Is there any generalisation for this approach to remove multiple rows and columns at the same time?